# In SQL Server Management Studio can I search for assets across multiple databases?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My everyday IDE is Eclipse which has a wonderful Open Resource feature (CTRL+SHIFT+R or Navigate > Open Resource) which allows the user to search for files/resources across multiple projects.

I can't find a similar feature in SQL Server Management Studio, is there one?

Comment: You mean, like searching for a column name through all tables in a db?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2005 and I was thinking of stored procedures, tables, views, etc. but columns would be good too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for objects in a sql database using the Information Schema Views
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx
There's one for tables, columns, functions, sprocs, etc.

select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.routines 
where ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%xp%_'

Answer (score 10):

I believe this is what you are looking for:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

It is completely free, and completely awesome.

[image]
<sub>(source: [red-gate.com](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/assets/images/fullview.png))</sub>

[image]

Comment: +1 Can't believe this isn't the accepted answer. Great tool! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no default mechanism in SMS to be able to search across projects.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sp_MSforeachdb like so:

```
sp_MSforeachdb 'SELECT * FROM ?.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.routines WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = ''PROCEDURE'''
```

The above will select all procedures across all databases and return them in different result sets. Using different views, you can also select tables, columns and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone has a better answer to this than I do.  In the past, I've used a CURSOR to search through all the databases and insert results into a temp table.  I could then select from the temp table and show the results.

I don't have this code laying around anymore.  If no one comes up with a better answer, I'll come back and edit this with some real code.  I would think that there'd be a DMV for this.  Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I made the following CLR stored proc to search all tables and all columns in a database with explicit parallelism. Maybe it does what you want. It doesn't search stored procs or functions, but you can look for values, column names, table names, etc, and it returns results in XML rows. Please note that this shouldn't be used in the day to day, but it's useful for occasional auditing or forensics/DBA tasks, and its definitely fast... Searches all tables on AdventureWorks in 2 seconds flat hosted on a modest desktop PC.

https://pastebin.com/RRTrt8ZN

```
/*
    This script creates a CLR stored procedure and its assembly on a database that will let you search for
    keywords separated by a space on all columns of all tables of all types except 'binary', 'varbinary', 'bit',
    'timestamp', 'image', 'sql_variant', and 'hierarchyid'. This was made as a CLR stored proc to take advantage
    of explicit parallelism to make the search a lot faster. Be aware that this will use many cores so only use
    this for occasional DBA work. This has the potential to cause a DDoS type of situation if broad searches with
    many results are hammered into the server, since each request can try to parallelize its search. An optional
    parameter exists to limit parallelism to a set number of cores. You can also set filters on the tables or
    columns to search, including logical operators OR, AND, NOT, and parenthesis (see examples below). Results
    are returned as XML rows.

    To install you need owner rights. Also, because SQL Server doesn't allow secondary CLR threads access to 
    the stored procedure context, we extract the connection string from the first context connection we make.
    This works fine, but only if you are connected with a trusted connection (using a Windows account).

    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- CLR access must be enabled on the instance for this to work. --
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;                     --
    -- GO                                                           --
    -- RECONFIGURE;                                                 --
    -- GO                                                           --
    -- sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;                               --
    -- GO                                                           --
    -- RECONFIGURE;                                                 --
    -- GO                                                           --
    ------------------------------------------------------------------

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Database needs to be flagged trustworthy to be able to access CLR assemblies. --
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;                           --
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Example usages:
    ---------------
    Using all available processors on the server:
        EXEC [dbo].[SearchAllTables] @valueSearchTerm = 'john michael'

    Limiting the server to 4 concurrent threads:
        EXEC [dbo].[SearchAllTables] @valueSearchTerm = 'john michael', @maxDegreeOfParallelism = 4

    Using logical operators in search terms:
        EXEC [dbo].[SearchAllTables] @valueSearchTerm = '(john or michael) and not jack', @tablesSearchTerm = 'not contact'

    Limiting search to table names and/or column names containing some search terms:
        EXEC [dbo].[SearchAllTables] @valueSearchTerm = 'john michael', @tablesSearchTerm = 'person contact', @columnsSearchTerm = 'address name'

    Limiting search results to the first row of each table where the terms are found:
        EXEC [dbo].[SearchAllTables] @valueSearchTerm = 'john michael', @getOnlyFirstRowPerTable = 1

    Limiting the search to the schema only automatically returns only the first row for each table:
        EXEC [dbo].[SearchAllTables] @tablesSearchTerm = 'person contact'

    Only return the search queries:
        EXEC [dbo].[SearchAllTables] @valueSearchTerm = 'john michael', @tablesSearchTerm = 'person contact', @onlyOutputQueries = 1

    Capturing results into temporary table and sorting:
        CREATE TABLE #temp (Result NVARCHAR(MAX));
        INSERT INTO #temp
            EXEC [dbo].[SearchAllTables] @valueSearchTerm = 'john';
        SELECT * FROM #temp ORDER BY Result ASC;
        DROP TABLE #temp;
*/
```